# Run command taking output from previous step on GitHub actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to make a GitHub action that builds a Hugo website, deploys it on Pinata and saves the output hash  of this last step to a txt file. I managed to achieve the first and second steps. And, for the third one, I've been trying to do it by running an "echo" command. However, I get this message: "You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 36"

How do I run the script taking the output from the step identified as "ipfs-pin"?

Here's my code:

```
name: deploy
 on:
  push:
   branches: [ main ]
   pull_request:
   branches: [ main ]
   workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
 build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@master
   - uses: jakejarvis/hugo-build-action@master
     with:
      args: --minify --buildDrafts
   - uses: anantaramdas/ipfs-pinata-deploy-action@v1.6.4
     id: ipfs-pin
      with:
       pin-name: '[my-pin-name]'
       path: './public'
       pinata-api-key: [API Key]
       pinata-secret-api-key: [secret API Key]
       verbose: true
       remove-old: true
  saves-hash-on-file:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
    with:
      node-version: '14'
  - run: echo ${{steps.build.ipfs-pin.hash}} > /.github/ipfs-hash.txt
```

Comment: Did you try adding `needs: build` on the second job configuration? If I'm not mistaken it's mandatory when you want to use outputs from the specific job. I would also try adding the ${{ ... }} echo part between `"`  to resolve the syntax error.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Ok! Thanks. I added the two things. However, I still get the syntax error. It appears to be on the last line before the second job.

Comment: I think I got what happened. First, it seems your indentation has a problem, I  reproduced the workflow to correct it without returning error here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester12.yml - Second: I didn't see it at first, but you forgot to add the `outputs` field at the job1 (build) level, without this you can't share the output on other jobs (I couldn't run it successfully as I don't have any credential to test). It should work if you copy/paste the workflow I shared using your credentials.

Comment: Let me know if it works, so that I add an official answer 

Comment: @GuiFalourd yeah, sure! It works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### First

It seems your indentation has a problem, [I reproduced the workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester12.yml) to correct it without returning error when pushing the workflow on the repository:

```yaml
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      hash: ${{ steps.ipfs-pin.outputs.hash }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: jakejarvis/hugo-build-action@master
        with:
          args: --minify --buildDrafts
      - uses: anantaramdas/ipfs-pinata-deploy-action@v1.6.4
        id: ipfs-pin
        with:
          pin-name: '[my-pin-name]'
          path: './public'
          pinata-api-key: '[API Key]'
          pinata-secret-api-key: '[secret API Key]'
          verbose: true
          remove-old: true

  saves-hash-on-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [build]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: echo ${{steps.build.outputs.hash}} > /.github/ipfs-hash.txt
```

##### Second

As you can see on the workflow above, I added the `outputs` field at the job1 (build) level, without this you can't share the output on other jobs.

[Reference about outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs)

Moreover, to share outputs between jobs, you will have to add the `needs: [build]` line at the job2 (saves-hash-on-file) level.

*Note: I couldn't run it successfully as I don't have any credential to test, but it should work if you copy/paste the workflow I shared using your credentials.*